# LDAP query to enumerate of all users of the subgroups of a group

Tags: ldap

This LDAP query successfully enumerates all users within a group:

```
memberOf=CN=MySubGroup1,OU=MyGroup1,OU=Global Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com
```

The group MyGroup1 has two subgroups: MySubGroup1, MySubGroup2.
In order to get all the users of MyGroup1, I could make a query to get the users of MySubGroup1, another query to get the users of MySubGroup1, and then make the union.

However, I am asking how I can achieve the same results with only one LDAP query,
asking for all the users within MyGroup1 and sub-groups.

Any idea?

Comment: In what programming language / system??

Comment: i am asking how to achieve that in one LDAP query. so, the answer is independent of the programming language (java, c, scala...).

Comment: I don't think you can do it in a straight LDAP query, sorry ....

Comment: Could somebody please illustrate this in Java?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a `subgroup`, just groups. The correct term is `subordinate`,
i.e., `cn=mysubgroup1` is subordinate to `ou=mygroup1`, and so forth.

Use the following parameters in an LDAP search request:

- base object: `OU=MyGroup1,OU=Global Groups,DC=mycompany,DC=com`
- search scope: `sub` if there is more than one 'level' beneath `ou=mygroup1`, `one` otherwise
- filter: `(|(cn=mysubgroup1)(cn=mysubgroup2))`
- requested attribute: whichever multi-valued attribute whose value is the distinguished name
  of each member of the group

These search request parameters should result in a search result with two entries, the distinguished
of each entry, and the attributes whose values are the distinguished names of the members of each group.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Seach best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Answer (score 3):

If your server is Microsoft Active Directory then you can use [some extended rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). One of those rules does basically what you are looking for. Look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/424706/107401).

Try this:

```
memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Some Group,OU=My Organization Unit,DC=company,DC=com
```

Quoting from that answer:

> [...] it is possible, when using Microsoft AD LDAP, to do authorization using nested groups by using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN matching rule. This is much faster than searching subgroups on the client, because it is done on the DC server with less queries over network.
>
> 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN This rule is limited to filters that apply to the DN. This is a special "extended match operator that walks the chain of ancestry in objects all the way to the root until it finds a match.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me my life!